# Congruence modulo 2 for q-series

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, partitions

This quest arose from certain calculations with integer partitions (having distinct parts) and the corresponding values of their *Dyson ranks*.

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this congruence true modulo $2$?
> $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{q^{\binom{n+1}2}}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1-q^j)}\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{q^m}{1-q^m}\equiv
> \sum_{n\geq0}q^{3n+2}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-q^{4j-1}).$$

**Clarification.** As Richard Stanley commented on this, I meant to say that after expanding the two $q$-series, the coefficients agree term-by-term modulo $2$.

Comment: What is $q$ here? Mathematica suggests that, for $q=1/2$, the left-hand side of your congruence is $1.519\ldots$ and the right-hand side is $0.281\ldots$.

Comment: He means that when both sides are expanded as a power series in $q$, the coefficients of $q^j$ are congruent mod 2 for all $j$.

Comment: @RichardStanley : Thank you for your comment. Later, I too gathered that that is what the OP must have meant. Is this a common convention, to say that the sums of two power series are congruent if their respective coefficients are congruent?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: sorry for confusion and thanks for your interest.

Comment: @RichardStanley: many thanks.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes, this is a common convention.

Comment: @IraGessel : Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this problem is now solved due to the answer given by Gjergji Zaimi to [my follow up question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420684/equality-of-two-q-series-proof). Proceed as follows:

The LHS is computed modulo $2$ by
\begin{align}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{q^{\binom{n+1}2}}{(q;q)_n}\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{q^m}{1-q^m}
&=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{q^{\frac{n(3n+1)}2}(1+q^{2n+1})(-q;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}
\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1+q^{2j}}{1-q^{2j}} \\
&=\sum_{n\geq1}q^{\frac{n(3n+1)}2}(1+q^{2n+1}). \tag2
\end{align}
The RHS is computed with the help of well-known identity (replace $x\rightarrow q^{-1}, q\rightarrow q^4$)
$$\sum_{k\geq0}x^{k+2}q^{k+1}\prod_{j=1}^k(1-xq^j)=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n\left(x^{3n+2}q^{\frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}2}+x^{3n+3}q^{\frac{(n+1)(3n+4)}2}\right)$$
so that
$$\sum_{n\geq0}q^{3n+2}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-q^{4k-1})
\equiv \sum_{n\geq0}
\left(q^{-3n-2}q^{2(n+1)(3n+2)}+q^{-3n-3}q^{2(n+1)(3n+4)}\right). \tag3$$
Now, just check (2) and (3) agree.